# Best way to include JUnit in our project?

Tags: java, junit, ant, classpath, portability

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) and I want to use JUnit in a project I'm doing (without IDE, just on Atom).

I heard about including JUnit in the classpath, but I'm not sure it's the best option, because if I add to the classpath for every new software at a certain point it'll become a mess and programs will break every time I modify the classpath.

What is the best solution?

Putting the JUnit jar file in the project and including it in the building process seams fine, but I should duplicate the jar file for every project.

Putting JUnit in a single place in my pc and including that path from all the project resolves this issue, but the program will not be portable because it depends on the path I have for JUnit...

P.S. I'm using Ant to build

Comment: Not really an answer but have you considered using more modern (and easier to use) build tools such as maven or gradle? Adding junit would then ba as simple as adding a couple of lines with the junit dependency in your build file.

Comment: I agree with @assylias and you should consider using Maven or Gradle instead of Ant. However, if you must or want to stay with using Ant then check out [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/).

Comment: I'll try gradle soon or later, but at the moment I'm just trying to learn how to manage libraries and similar things